# How can I get a maven build to fail on duplicate dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, maven-dependency-plugin

If I have two dependencies which are the same in the same pom, I want the build to fail. Currently I can detect it happening with the Maven Dependency Plugin's "analyze-duplicate". However, there's no option to failOnWarning like some of the others (plus, it prints at Info level, not Warning). Is there an alternative to extending this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, when you want the build to fail for some reason, the good plugin to look into the [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/). This plugin can be configured with a set of rules that, when verified, will fail the build.

In this case, it would need to be a rule that checks for duplicate dependencies, and there is a built-in rule just for that: `<banDuplicatePomDependencyVersions>`. As such, you could have

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce-no-duplicate-dependencies</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <banDuplicatePomDependencyVersions/>
        </rules>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This rule is unfortunately not documented (yet, it will be in the next version, see [MENFORCER-259](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-259)), but it exists since version 1.3 of the plugin ([MENFORCER-152](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-152)).

What this rule does is checking that there are no 2 duplicate declaration with the same `'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)'`; which is to say that two declared dependencies with the same group id and artifact id declared in the POM will have to have a different type and/or classifier.

Comment: For some reason, I can only get it to print a warning. It never fails. I tried forcing both the `fail` and `failFast` flags, but still only get warnings. ‍♂️

Comment: It seems the rule `banDuplicatePomDependencyVersions` does not detect duplicate declarations in the `dependencyManagement` section. I still get a warning despite using the rule: `[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique`